# iPhone default data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dataset, default-value

I'm developing an iPhone application with a default list of items in a table, as well as any custom items that a user adds, which I put into an array. At the moment I simply create every default object one by one in the "ViewDidLoad" method for that view. I would like to know if there's a better way of creating default data for an iPhone app that's going to ship with the app when you put it on a new device.

Thanks,
JheeBz

Comment: Are you using Core Data? It is a fairly simple thing to have a #define action which you can run to generate your .sqlite and then copy the default database as required into the app's documents directory.

Comment: No I'm not using Core Data. I've really had no need for a database so far.

Comment: If you are just populating an array to fill a table from then you could use a plist or JSON.

Comment: How would you recommend I go about creating the plist. Creating the array and then saving it to a plist, deleting the code and then loading the plist? Or manually editing the XML?

Comment: You create all your objects already - so just put all your data in a NSMutableDictionary and then use "- (BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString *)path atomically:(BOOL)flag" - presto! Instant plist. That's the easiest way. I find manually editing XML, even through the plist editor, to be very error prone.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `plist` resource describing an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. Find the path for the resource in the main bundle, and use this to inflate to a dictionary or array.

Go to `File -> New File -> iOS Resource -> Property List`.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the worst thing you are doing is `create every default object one by one in the "ViewDidLoad"`. This is very bad design and is not at all advisable.

Regardless of how you manage your data, file(plist/json), database or whatever. I would highly recommend managing your data in a singleton class that can set-up the defaults **once and once only** and then later **read/modify/delete/add** from within your ViewController.

This will separate the data logic from your view, and abstract it from your storage mechanism.

That aside you could easily use a file such as **JSON** for the initial defaults and persist the users changes with `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:(id) forKey:(NSString)]` for setting and `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:(NSstring*)]` for accessing.

Happy Coding :)